# how to export db sql database to microsoft access database mdb?

Tags: database, convert, microsoft, sqlite

i need to export a database in "db" format to access database "mdb" in Ubuntu
db browser for sql lite don't have the option to export to mdb - it just have the option to export to csv or sql

i also installed DBeaver and i couldn't find that option

so is there a way to convert from sql or db to mdb in linux?

Comment: If it needs to be a fully function MS Access database, you may have more success on a Windows-based system. The SQL Lite source can be copied over, then converted using Access itself 

Comment: Please provide your OS & release details.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly" "db format" does not mean anything, luckily you also mention "SQLite".  I don't see the relation with Ubuntu, but I'll answer anyway.

You even don't have to export or import. MS Access knows how to access databases using ODBC (create links to tables in any ODBC database).

Download the ODBC driver for SQLite from http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/ (MS Windows only), and follow its documentation.

If you insist to have the content of tables in the .mdb itself, a few INSERT ..... SELECT .....; statements will suffice to do the conversion.

Alternatively: In the SQLite command line interface (sqlite3.exe) you can use the .schema and .dump commands to export the schema DDL, or the schema DDL plus data DML, respectively. That SQL is very basic, and in some cases not compatible with MS Access, so you may have to tweak it a bit.